# Редактирование post_type в wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Люди вот подскажите... Бьюсь кучу времени... Как регистрировать новые **`post_type`** - это понятно через **`register_post_type($name,$args)`**;

А вот как изменить такие `post_type` как **`post`** и **`page`**... например, переименовать там всё через **`$labels = array( );`** или добавитьисключить там что-то... через **`'supports' => array('title','editor','custom-fields')`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Изменение стандартных надписей в Админке для записей...
function change_post_object_label() {
    global $wp_post_types;
    $labels = $wp_post_types['post']->labels;
    $labels->name = __('Акции', 'new' );
    $labels->singular_name = __('Акции', 'new' );
    $labels->add_new = __('Добавить', 'new' );
    $labels->add_new_item = __('Добавить', 'new' );
    $labels->edit_item = __('Редактирование акции', 'new' );
    $labels->new_item = __('Новая акция', 'new' );
    $labels->view_item = __('Просмотр акции', 'new' );
    $labels->search_items = __('Поиск акции', 'new' );
    $labels->not_found = __('Акция не найдена', 'new' );
    $labels->not_found_in_trash = __('Акция не найдена', 'new' );
    $labels->menu_name = __('Акции', 'new' );
    $labels->name_admin_bar = __('Акции', 'new' );
    $labels->all_items = __('Все акции', 'new' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'change_post_object_label' );
```